# How to match my categories with tags detected in image using Google vision api?

Tags: image, matching, google-vision, vision-api

I tag pictures using vision api. How do I **categorize** images using these tags?

Comment: Which vision api feature are you using? How do you tag your pictures? You send an image into vision api and get some result back?

Comment: I' m using Vision API and I have label and category dataset. I want after tagging my images with VISION API, compare them with my own data set.